# Typo3 backend login don't login, no error

Tags: typo3-11.x

[image]

I'm trying to login to a fresh Typo3 v11 copy but login don't work.
to reproduce this issue:

Setup a fresh install Typo3 v11, i put my login and password in backend.
after click on login it load for 1sec then stay in same page. nothing happen, just keep showing the login form.

I have re-installed the project and copy the .htaccess file from the install source code but this didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have deleted cookies for this website, now login works. probably the browser still keeps old website cookies.

Also this issue can be caused by an empty cookie domain, you have to be sure that the following field is correct: [SYS][cookieDomain].

Answer (score 1):

TYPO3 probably misses your cookies.
either you have redirecting (e.g. http to https or another domain)
or you have restricted the IP (`$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['BE']['lockIP']`) and switch the IP because of proxy or loadbalancer.

Comment: have redirecting (e.g. http to https or another domain), how can i check this? this site is brand new install.
['BE']['lockIP'] >> i check, nothing like this is in localconf file.